# Save input from bash script

Tags: bash, input

I making a form using bash script.
I want the user to choose the name of the save file.

echo whats your name?
read name?

echo how old are you?
read age?

what do u want to call the save file?
Myname

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: look this one http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_form_dialog_for_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yad may be useful in this regard, it is a fork of zenity with more features, one of them the ability to create forms.

For install yad goto

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html

You can create simple form by

```
#!/bin/bash


frmdata=$(yad --title "Test Form" --form --field "Address" --field="Name")


frmaddr=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')
frmname=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $2 }')

echo $frmaddr > test.txt
echo $frmname >> test.txt
```

[image]

After you enter your data and click ok or hit enter on the keyboard, the form data will be written to a text file called `test.txt`

more example

http://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/Examples